# BinaryContent Stream wrapper in Grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to write a simple wrapper in grails that will read a binary file from a non-public back-end web-server and makes it available as a stream to a public server.
The first question is what is the best method to handle such a solution considering that the Grails will attempt to render views by default.

I am attempting a solution which leads to an "Attempted read from closed stream." which apparently looks to avoid the view rendering by invoking response but I am not sure if this is a good solution anyway.

I am reading the back-end file through the following code:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)
http.request(method, ContentType.BINARY) {
                uri.path = path
                uri.query = query
                response.success = { resp, inputstream ->
                    log.info "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
                    resp.headers.each { h -> log.info " ${h.name} : ${h.value}" }
                    return inputstream
                }
```

and later attempt to push it to the client through the following method in a controller:

```
def binary(){
      response.outputStream << getBinaryContent("http://aaa" );
      response.flush()
    }
```

Error: "Attempted read from closed stream."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken `<<` will close the response so `response.flush()` is invalid.

Here's the snippet that I use for CSV, just replace with your content type:

```
byte[] bytes = fileGenerated.getBytes() //fileGenerated is a File
response.setContentType("text/csv")
response.setContentLength(bytes.length)
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileGenerated.getName())
response.outputStream << bytes
```

Comment: Removing the response.flush() did not help and the message is the same. 
I am trying not to download a file and then stream it, but to stream it as I receive it.

Comment: Solved by returning inputStream.getBytes() in the HttpBuilder and reading them as mentioned above by Sergio Michels